# Object in Flash scope is not available after redirect

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, flash-scope

I have a misunderstanding with the use of flash scope in jsf 2.
I want to put an object in flash map during my action and show this object in the next page.
Here is my action (call by h:commandLink):

```
public String showDetail(PersonneDTO personne) {
    MessageFlashBean message = new MessageFlashBean();
    message.addMessage("test");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash()
        .put("test", message);
    return "showDetail";
}
```

It's just a test, but the real object I want to use is more complex.

Here is the second page with the flash use:

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{flash.test != null and flash.test.hasMessage()}" >
    <ui:repeat var="message" value="#{flash.test.messages}">
        #{message}
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:fragment>
```

Here is the navigation (and here is my problem :) ):

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>showDetail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/private/showDetail.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

In this case, the flash scope works fine and my message appears.

But if I add a redirect in the navigation case, my object in the flash map has disappeared.

I don't understand why I can't use redirect in the navigation rule (I believed it was the goal of flash scope).

May be something is wrong in  my code.

Someone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried on JSF 2.0.3.FCS, it did survive a redirect.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Mojarra's implementation of the JSF2 Flash scope [had a lot of problems](http://java.net/jira/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project%20=%20JAVASERVERFACES%20AND%20%28summary%20~%20flash%20OR%20description%20~%20flash%20OR%20comment%20~%20flash%29). Most of them were resolved with every new Mojarra release. Currently, with the latest [Mojarra version](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/), the 2.1.6, there's as far as I know still only one major open problem: it won't work if you redirect to a different base path. See also the (currently) last comment in the long discussion in [issue 1751](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1751).

Right now, you have basically the following options:

1. Forget using Flash when you need to redirect to a different base path. Use a request parameter instead or try to simulate the flash scope with a custom cookie.
2. If possible, reorganize the folder structure so that you don't need to redirect to a different base path when you need the flash scope to survive.
3. Try [MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/) instead of Mojarra. Maybe it does it better with regard to flash scope.

---

**Update**: as per [issue 2136](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2136), the last open problem of Flash scope not being available after a redirect on a different path is solved in the shortly upcoming **Mojarra 2.1.14**. So with this version, *all* Flash scope related problems discovered and open so far 
should be solved and closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use Mojarra 2.1.6 and I hadn't seen this bug. It's exactly my case. I'll try to go back to the 2.0.3 version

Answer (score 2):

jsf 2.1 with netbeans has this problem with flash. using `/somepage?redirect-faces=true or /somedirectory/somepage?faces-redirect=true`  does not work. it has to be `somepage?redirect-faces=true`.

tested mojarra 2.1.7, but it didn't have the above problem.