# Keeping flash via #{flash.keep.foo} does not to work, instead #{flash.foo} works

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, keep-alive, flash-scope

I have an app running with Primefaces, JSF 2.2, Spring and Hibernate. 
I use JSF's Flash Scope to send a parameter with a redirection:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("loginCliente", cliente.getLogin());
return "registroCasa?faces-redirect=true";
```

If I write `#{flash.keep.loginCliente}` in `registroCasa.xhtml` and I reload the page the value becomes null, but if I write `#{flash.loginClient}` the value keeps alive. Why?

I'm using Mojarra 2.2.12.

Comment: Flash works ok with MyFaces implementation. Maybe is a bug as says BalusC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148798/object-in-flash-scope-is-not-available-after-redirect