# Flash data is lost after JSF page reload

Tags: jsf, flash-scope

I implemented JSF Flash in pages:

**First page:**

```
<h:commandLink value="#{item.number}" action="#{accounts.pageRedirect}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{accounts.sessionValue}" value="#{item.number}" />
</h:commandLink>

public void setSessionValue(Object value) throws IOException
{
    Flash flash = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash();
    flash.put("obj", value);
    flash.setKeepMessages(true);

}

public String pageRedirect()
{
    return "/accounts/AccountProfile.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

**Second page:**

```
@PostConstruct
public void initData()
{
    id = (int) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("obj");
}
```

Both pages are in `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`

This solution works but I want when I reload the second page to keep again the value. Now I get NPE when I try to lead the second page. Is there any solution. I can use Session scope but these should be some other more simple solution.

Comment: did you take a look on this answer ?. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148798/object-in-flash-scope-is-not-available-after-redirect

Comment: You can use `#{flash.keep.obj}` in the page itself, but this is fishy. What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Are you well aware of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521451? Ask yourself: how exactly should the page behave when enduser copypastes/bookmarks/shares URL and opens it in an entirely different session/application?

Comment: @BalusC is this `flash.setKeepMessages(true);` same as `#{flash.keep.obj}`?

Comment: [Nope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/Flash.html).

Comment: I tested it but the the result is the same. I get NPE here `id = (int) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().get("obj");` when I execute `<f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>` or page refresh. Any other proposals?